# Importing Python files (modules) from another Python file in C++ PyBind11

Tags: python, c++, module, embed, pybind11

Ok. So since my issue on Github wasn't properly answered and I was suggested to go to a proper forum, here I am. I am trying to import a Python file from another Python file with embedded PyBind11. The problem goes like this:

I have two files:
*mts.py*:

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b
```

and *main.py*:

```
print('Hello, world!')
```

And I have my C++ code:

```
py::initialize_interpreter(); // I am purposely not using eval_file because in the future I might not be using files, but strings instead.
py::exec(readFile("mts.py"));
py::exec(readFile("main.py"));
py::finalize_interpreter();
```

My question is, how can I import 'mts.py' in 'main.py'? i.e. How can I call 'add' in 'main.py'?

Comment: Please edit question. Now question is about `.py`  files only and doesn't explain what you want to accomplish in C++ and how it's related to python files.

Comment: The question is about both! How am I supposed to edit the C++ code, so it allows me to import one Python file into another?

Answer (score 0):

Well, by logic, you can call it from main.py, like *main.py*:

```
# I import the function "add ()" from the file (be sure to prescribe the full path from the executive file *.exe or ./*)
# It is important for a built -in interpreter to register a full path from a executable file for PYBIND11
# Simple file hierarchy
# -dir-
#   |-main.cpp
#   |-main.exe or main (Executable)
#   |-scripts
#       |-mnt.py
#       |-main.py
from scripts.mnt import add

# if file hierarchy is such
# -dir-
#   |-main.cpp
#   |-main.exe or main (Executable)
#   |-mnt.py
#   |-main.py
from mnt import add

# call function example
add ( 4, 4 ) # 8
```

I hope I helped solve your problem.